# Batch Reading text file, and being able to use it as valid input

Tags: file, batch-file, text, input, load

i'm currently creating a batch file that has to tell which files the desired folder contains, and being able to promt those file names. From there i want an input field where you enter the name of the file, which will in that case, open the file.

I really someone would be able to help me, this is my current code for this part

```
    :dan
cls
echo Finding files in danish
echo.
dir C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\Skoe\dansk\ /b > files.txt %fi%
dir C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\Skoe\dansk\ /b %fi%
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
set /p sr=Which file do you wish to start?
// this is where i need the code to check if the user entered a file name that is in that // folder, and if it is a valid file, send the user to :filestart where hes file will be //started
pause
:filestart
echo filstart
// here i need the desired file started
```

Comment: What happens when there is more than one screen full of filenames?  There is another method where you display the names with a number, and get the user to type just the number.  Is that any use to you?

Comment: Didn't you feel like answering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
cls
echo Finding files in danish
echo.
dir C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\Skoe\dansk\ /b > files.txt %fi%
dir C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\Skoe\dansk\ /b %fi%
echo.
echo.
:readFileName
echo.
echo.
set /p sr=Which file do you wish to start? 
IF EXIST dansk\%sr% (
goto filestart
) else (
echo %sr% does not exist.
echo Please try again.
goto readFileName
)
pause
:filestart
echo filestart %sr%
start dansk\%sr%
```

Comment: I'm having a problem with this code. The "danish" This batch file is located in the "Skoe" Folder, and the "danish files" are stored in a subfolder called "dansk" So whenever i type in the file name, it says file dosen't exists. Your feedback is appreciated